# Is it possible to create a rollup property for an app and desktop site?

Tags: google-analytics

The need: a combined number of total ***some metric*** across two mobile apps and a desktop site. The question: can I implement trackers as needed (SDK and JS) that share a property ID?

My guess: no, as the hit types won't match, and either pageview or screenview hit types won't be processed (based on the property configuration).

Further question: though it won't be possible for this implementation, conceivably I could implement the measurement protocol on all apps/sites and set the hit type as whatever (as long as it matched across all apps/sites), correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed are supposed to create separate properties for the apps and the website - cf.  [Best practices for Mobile App Analytics setup](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en).

In order to get your consolidated reporting, you could use the google analytics API to get the raw data, and aggregate the measures by yourself.

To reply to your further question: Yes, technically, it is possible to hack the measurement protocol this way. Just push virtual pageviews, custom dimensions/measures, or events, however you like.

Actually, one solution for you may be to use  one property per app/website as recommended, plus in addition use an extra property where you just record custom data the way you want, across the apps and the website.

Comment: Any chance you (or anyone out there) has actually tried to send screenview hit types to a property set up as a desktop site (or vice versa)? I'm interested in what actually happens under these conditions - can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @Tom I have no idea. You could try and see how it behaves (please share the result too, I'm interested)

Comment: I meant to update this when I was still working on it, but IIRC, if the hit type of a request does not match (or is not a compatible hit type with, e.g. social) the configuration of the property, then the request is discarded (or at least not processed).